# Is port number 1099 is specific to JBoss?

Tags: jboss

I am using JBoss5 and using ejb. In all the examples of ejb I found the port number is 1099 for lookup, but as I saw the server.xml file budefault JBoss runs in the port 8080.

Is this any specific port number to JBoss?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [port numbers assignment](http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers) 1099 is "RMI Registry"